# Distinguishing a vector from a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I'm making a helper function for this project I'm working on in which I need to make percentiles out of a set of data.

In some instances, I'll be percentiling a vector of entries, which is fairly easy. In other instances, I'll be percentiling entries in a matrix.

The processes are similar, but different. I'd like to be able to distinguish what is given as an input (whether it's a vector or a matrix) so I know what operation is appropriate.

I thought about doing something with the dimensions of the input. But `dim(*vector*) = NULL`, but `dim(matrix(1:15, 1,15)) = c(1,15)` even though that is debatable to be  a vector. So I can't use my first idea of

```
if(length(dim(objects)) == 2){*A MATRIX*}
else{*A VECTOR*}
```

I considered that I could just add the condition of `min(dim(objects)) > 1` to test for a matrix, but I'm thinking there is probably a better option. (And now I'm here...)

Any thoughts?

Comment: you could probably use `?is.vector` and `?is.matrix`?

Comment: This has the same issue of `is.matrix(matrix(1,1,2)) = TRUE` but it's dimensions are `c(1,2)` so it technically is still a vector

Comment: then maybe: `is.vector(x) | min(dim(x)) > 1`?

Comment: yeah, I think `is.vector(x) | min(dim(x)) == 1` should work. I was wondering if there was something better, but it might not get any better haha. Thanks

Comment: or `ncol(x)>1 | nrow(x)>1` should also do the job

Comment: jameselmore: technically, schmechnically - it's a matrix with a degenerate dimension, degeneracy can have dimension 1 or 0

Comment: @mdsumner, I guess my "technically a vector" statement was born out of my mathematical training. Haha, I'm a mathematician first, computer scientist second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you want to ignore any dimension that only has one level, so `drop` would be appropriate:

```
if(is.null(dim(drop(x)))) {
  # do vector stuff
} else {
  # do matrix/array stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up finding (for this particular problem) a way around all of this. BUT, I didn't know of that function, and it's a good one..

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `prop.table` for the operations? You can get either row or column proportions and if you wnat percentiles you can multiply by 100 and round to the desired accuracy

```
> m <- matrix(1:9, 3)
> prop.table(m, 1)
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.08333333 0.3333333 0.5833333
[2,] 0.13333333 0.3333333 0.5333333
[3,] 0.16666667 0.3333333 0.5000000
> prop.table(m,2)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.1666667 0.2666667 0.2916667
[2,] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
[3,] 0.5000000 0.4000000 0.3750000

> round(100*prop.table(m, 1), 2) # rounded row percentages
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  8.33 33.33 58.33
[2,] 13.33 33.33 53.33
[3,] 16.67 33.33 50.00
```